# appending a element if more than one condition is satisfied jquery

Tags: jquery, operators

here is the code

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16 && $("#search").length >4) 
    {
       append
}
```

the after part of and operator does not work

whati am actually trying to do is to add an element to div if shift key is pressed and length of the input field is more than 4

Comment: the code works if i remove the and operator so i am probably doing something wrong with validation

Comment: use $("#search").val().length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current statement `$("#search").length > 4` means you have more than four elments with id `search` to get this statement true. You probably need to check the `value` of input that it should have more than four characters, You need to use `val()` to get the value of input field.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16 && $("#search").val().length > 4) 
    {
       append
    }
}
```

Using native javascript to get performance benefit.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16 && document.getElementById("search").value.length > 4) 
    {
       append
    }
}
```